Merge the content of flow files if same flow file Attributevalues
I want to merge the content of flow files into single flow file if we found any matches in flow file attribute value.
I donot know the exact values of flow files attribute values so I can't use routeonattribute so directly I want to use mergecontent

In MergeContent Properties. Make sure Keep Only Common Attributes is set for Attribute Strategy and for Correlation Attribute Name - set the common attribute name that matches across different flow files.
I have attached the image below for your reference
MergeContent Properties
